# Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64') LinearRegression: but there are no empty values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, linear-regression

Originally, my input dataset had blank spaces. But I have cleaned it, and checked with:
df.isnull().sum()
And everthing is 0.
Now, after fitting my dataset into the LinearRegression model and about to make predictions, it's bringing the above error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you did mention that the error is happening during the prediction time, I would suggest that you make the testing data go through the same pipeline as the training data.

For example:

raw training input -> preprocessing -> training input

It is necessary the test data also goes through the same preprocessing.

Comment: Thank You!! It worked!! I have being working on the train dataset alone all these while.

Comment: Glad to help. Please make sure to mark it as the accepted answer if it has worked.